# What is the lightest way of doing this task?

Tags: python

I have a file whose contents are of the form:

```
.2323  1
.2327  1
.3432  1
.4543  1
```

and so on some 10,000 lines in each file.
I have a variable whose value is say a=.3344

From the file I want to get the row number of the row whose first column is closest to this variable...for example it should give row_num='3' as .3432 is closest to it.

I have tried in a method of loading the first columns element in a list and then comparing the variable to each element and getting the index number

If I do in this method it is very much time consuming and slow my model...I want a very quick method as this need to to called some 1000 times minimum...

I want a method with least overhead and very quick can anyone please tell me how can it be done very fast.
As the file size is maximum of 100kb can this be done directly without loading into any list of anything...if yes how can it be done.

Any method quicker than the method mentioned above are welcome but I am desperate to improve the speed -- please help.

```
def get_list(file, cmp, fout):
    ind, _ = min(enumerate(file), key=lambda x: abs(x[1] - cmp))
    return fout[ind].rstrip('\n').split(' ')

#root = r'c:\begpython\wavnk'
header = 6
for lst in lists:
    save = database_index[lst]
    #print save
    index, base,abs2, _ , abs1 = save
    using_data[index] = save

    base = 'C:/begpython/wavnk/'+ base.replace('phone', 'text')
    fin, fout = base + '.pm', base + '.mcep'
    file = open(fin)
    fout = open(fout).readlines()
    [next(file) for _ in range(header)]
    file = [float(line.partition(' ')[0]) for line in file]
    join_cost_index_end[index] = get_list(file, float(abs1), fout)
    join_cost_index_strt[index] = get_list(file, float(abs2), fout)
```

this is the code i was using..copying file into a list.and all please give better alternarives to this

Comment: Are the values in the file in sorted numeric order?  Are they all 4-digit fractions?

Comment: yes there are sorted in increasing order..original file has all decimal upto 6 significant bits example .545454

Comment: background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046145/can-this-code-be-further-optimized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load it into a list then use [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html).

Comment: Since the lines are fixed length, it's possible to use a custom class to pull the items out on demand instead of reading them all into a list. For 100kB it is unlikely to to be worth the effort though

Answer (score 3):

Is the data in the file sorted in numerical order? Are all the lines of the same length? If not, the simplest approach is best. Namely, reading through the file line by line. There's no need to store more than one line in memory at a time.

#### Code:

```
def closest(num):
    closest_row   = None
    closest_value = None

    for row_num, row in enumerate(file('numbers.txt')):
        value = float(row.split()[0])

        if closest_value is None or abs(value - num) < abs(closest_value - num):
            closest_row     = row
            closest_row_num = row_num
            closest_value   = value

    return (closest_row_num, closest_row)

print closest(.3344)
```

#### Output for sample data:

```
(2, '.3432  1\n')
```

If the lines are all the same length and the data is sorted then there are some optimizations that will make this a very fast process. All the lines being the same length would let you seek directly to particular lines (you can't do this in a normal text file with lines of different length). Which would then enable you to do a binary search.

A binary search would be massively faster than a linear search. A linear search will on average have to read 5,000 lines of a 10,000 line file each time, whereas a binary search would on average only read log<sub>2</sub> 10,000 ≈ **13** lines.

Comment: please can u just illustrate with help of some code for file with same length..how to apply binary search and all thnq for the reply

Comment: @kaki: in your comment on the question you said the first column has values with _up to_ 6 decimal places, but now you say all the lines are the same length... which is it?

Comment: upto 6 decimal points means every element has 6 digits after the point..no matter if it is an interger also such as
1.000000
2.345450
0.343215
etc

Comment: _up to_ 6 means anything between 0 and 6; sounds like what you mean is _exactly_ 6 decimal places. (It would probably be less confusing if the example data in your question had the same format as the lines in your actual data file)

Comment: @John: `file`? really? you haven't heard of `enumerate` either?

Comment: @kaki: this code is no different from [the one I gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046145/can-this-code-be-further-optimized/3046664#3046664). It is only less efficient and less pythonic. Storing of the file in a list, John, was needed because OP wanted two indexes from the same file, for two different values of `a`. The only difference with the previous question is that the file is apparently sorted, in which case you should be using Ignacio's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Building on John Kugelman's answer, here's a way you might be able to do a binary search on a file with fixed-length lines:

```
class SubscriptableFile(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file
        file.seek(0,0)
        self._line_length = len(file.readline())
        file.seek(0,2)
        self._len = file.tell() / self._line_length
    def __len__(self):
        return self._len
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self._file.seek(key * self._line_length)
        s = self._file.readline()
        if s:
            return float(s.split()[0])
        else:
            raise KeyError('Line number too large')
```

This class wraps a file in a list-like structure, so that now you can use the functions of the `bisect` module on it:

```
def find_row(file, target):
    fw = SubscriptableFile(file)
    i = bisect.bisect_left(fw, target)
    if fw[i + 1] - target < target - fw[i]:
        return i + 1
    else:
        return i
```

Here `file` is an open file object and `target` is the number you want to find. The function returns the number of the line with the closest value.

I will note, however, that the `bisect` module will try to use a C implementation of its binary search when it is available, and I'm not sure if the C implementation supports this kind of behavior. It might require a true list, rather than a "fake list" (like my `SubscriptableFile`).

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, exactly what I was thinking of. @Kaki, if this works I'd accept this answer as it'll be a thousand times faster than my linear search.

Comment: this isnt working!! i am getting error saying list index out of range at get_item return float(s.split()[0])...

Comment: what u said is correct bisect require true list wat to do now

Comment: @kaki: the error you're seeing ("list index out of range") seems to indicate that there is a blank line in your file. Empty lines will mess this up because they are only 1 character long (the newline character), not the same length as the other lines. So if you have any empty lines in the file (even at the end!), delete them. (Except that the very last character in the file should be a newline) In practice, it's probably simpler to just load the nonempty lines into a list and use `bisect` on that, if you have enough memory (and 100KB should not present a problem on any modern computer).